# How to convert data using SQL Pivot table

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert below mentioned table rows to columns using pivot table (dynamic column) where in table Article Number,Article Name,Catalog Code  are fixed columns .Your help will be highly appreciated

```
ArticleNumber   ArticleName CatalogCode AttributeName   AttributeValue
s123              abc         1          SportsCategory     Rakesh
s123              abc         1          Brand              Amar
s123              abc         1          ProductDivision    Ball
s123              abc         1          MarketingDivision  Boss
s222              XYZ         1          SportsCategory     Rakesh5
s222              XYZ         1          Brand              Red
s222              XYZ         1          ProductDivision    blue
s222              XYZ         1          SportsCategory     Rakesh8
```

**OutPut:**

```
ArticleNumber   ArticleName CatalogCode SportsCategory  Brand   ProductDivision MarketingDivision
s123             abc          1          Rakesh         Amar     Ball           Boss
s222             abc          1          Rakesh5        Red      blue           Rakesh8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: My answer is usefull or not if it is usefull then mark it as accept. -Amardeep P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a simple pivot

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (Article varchar(4), Name varchar(3), Code int, Attribute varchar(17), AttributeValue varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Article, Name, Code, Attribute, AttributeValue)
VALUES
    ('s123', 'abc', 1, 'SportsCategory', 'Rakesh'),
    ('s123', 'abc', 1, 'Brand', 'Amar'),
    ('s123', 'abc', 1, 'ProductDivision', 'Ball'),
    ('s123', 'abc', 1, 'MarketingDivision', 'Boss'),
    ('s222', 'XYZ', 1, 'SportsCategory', 'Rakesh5'),
    ('s222', 'XYZ', 1, 'Brand', 'Red'),
    ('s222', 'XYZ', 1, 'ProductDivision', 'blue'),
    ('s222', 'XYZ', 1, 'SportsCategory', 'Rakesh8')
;

Select Article, Name, Code, [SportsCategory],[Brand],[ProductDivision],[MarketingDivision] from (
select Article, Name, Code, Attribute, AttributeValue from @Table1)T
PIVOT (MAX(AttributeValue) FOR Attribute IN ([SportsCategory],[Brand],[ProductDivision],[MarketingDivision]))P
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT ARTICLE, NAME, CODE, ATTRIBUTENAME, ATTRIBUTEVALUE
  FROM #TABLE1
) D
PIVOT
(
  MAX(ATTRIBUTEVALUE)
  FOR ATTRIBUTENAME IN  ([SPORTSCATEGORY],[BRAND],[PRODUCTDIVISION],[MARKETINGDIVISION])
) PIV;``
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer so it can be of use to later questioners as well.